# Converting SimpleDateFormat to String

Tags: java, string, date, type-conversion

I'm having a user enter a date, the date entered is a `SimpleDateFormat`. `dd-MM-yyyy`.
I save this in a Class Object and then want to display it. 
When I display this in a `JOptionPane` message box, it shows something like this:

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat@9586200
```

What could cause this, or how can I convert it to a string and display that?
Here is the code where I convert the date entered from string to date.
Now I store the `fDate` into a `SimpleDateFormat flightDate;` in the object.

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    fDate.setLenient(false);
    fDate.parse(dateText);
    Main.flightObjects[Main.flightCount].setFlightDate(fDate);
} catch(java.text.ParseException d) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
    "Please make sure your date is in the correct format! dd-mm-yyyy\n e.g. 16-03-2013", "Date Error 1", 1);
}
```

---

```
 String dateS = (String)flightDate.format(flightDate);

 String output = "Flight num: " + flightNumber + "\nDate: " + dateS + "\nDeparting City: " + departCity + "\nArrival City: " + arriveCity + "\nAvailable Seats: " + seatsAvailable + "\nSold Seats: " + seatsSold + "\nSeat Price: R" + seatPrice;

 return output;
```

The `^` is how I want to display the date. How would I to the conversion back to `String`? `flightDate` was declared as `SimpleDateFormat flightDate;` and the date was assigned to it from the Code in try-catch.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is just a class to convert from Date to String

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in your program. See updated code below (note variable **dateValue** ):

```
try
{
    SimpleDateFormat fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    fDate.setLenient(false);
    Date dateValue = fDate.parse(dateText);
    Main.flightObjects[Main.flightCount].setFlightDate(dateValue);
}
catch(java.text.ParseException d)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
    "Please make sure your date is in the correct format! dd-mm-yyyy\n e.g. 16-03-2013",
    "Date Error 1",1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I very much doubt that you actually want to set anything to a `SimpleDateFormat`. I'd expect you to set it to the `Date` that's *parsed* by the `SimpleDateFormat`, that you're currently ignoring the return value of:

```
Main.flightObjects[Main.flightCount].setFlightDate(fDate.parse(dateText));
```

(Your `setFlightDate` method should accept a `Date` or perhaps `Calendar`, not `DateFormat`.)

A `SimpleDateFormat` isn't a date - it's just a text/date converter.

To convert the `Date` back to a string later, you'd use `format` instead of `parse`:

```
String text = fDate.format(Main.flightObjects[Main.flightCount].getFlightDate());
```

As an aside, it looks like you're using an array when a `List<Flight>` would be much more sensible. Also, you might want to consider using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which is a far better date/time API.

Comment: Hi; thanks for the info. :-) But for some reason I just can't get it to work... :-/
I made a eddit with my display code.

Comment: @EnthusedDragon: You haven't shown the type of `flightDate`, but whatever type it is, you shouldn't be trying to get it to format itself! You need to pass a `Date` into `DateFormat.format`.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps, convert it to string. like below:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

// Get the date
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();        
// Using DateFormat format method we can create a string 
String reportDate = df.format(today);

// Print date or do what ever you like to do with it
System.out.println("Report Date: " + reportDate);
```